# Как скопировать из vim в буфер X сервера?

Tags: vim, clipboard, tmux

B терминале Tilda запущен сеанс tmux с vim. Нужно копипастить фрагменты через буфер обмена x сервера.

Средствами редактора (чтобы не захватывалась нумерация строк и соседние тайлы tmux) я делаю это так:

```
:'<,'>!xclip -sel clip
```

— скопировать выделение в буфер обмера X сервера. (требуется xclip)

Правда после этого надо жать u, потому, что идёт не копирование а вырезание, почему-то.

Как сделать именно копирование?

Comment: Если вам помогло какое-то решение из уже предложенных, то примите его. Если нет, то пожалуйста оставте замечание комментарием - почему нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такая конструкция:

```
:<диапазон>!<команда оболочки>
```

использует `команду оболочки` как фильтр — передаёт ей (на *stdin*) указанный `диапазон` строк, и всё, что команда запишет в свой *stdout*, используется как замена для указанного дипазона строк.

чтобы замены не происходило, можно воспользоваться командой `:write` (пробел после команды обязателен, иначе ошибку получите):

```
:<диапазон>write !<команда оболочки>
```

имя данной команды для удобства можно сократить до одной буквы (`w`).

в вашем примере:

```
:'<,'>w !xclip -sel clip
```

---

доп. чтение: `:h :w_c`

Comment: Спасибо, но попутно он мне скроллит экран на строку с "Нажмите ENTER или введите команду для продолжения". Можно ли этого избежать?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел свои файлы и нашел только следующее:

tmux.conf

```
set -g set-clipboard on
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

init.vim

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

Работаю в neovim.
Если выделяю фрагмент мышкой то для копирования просто нажимаю Enter.
Если в редакторе выделяю с помощью v (режим VISUAL), то прост нажимаю y.
В обоих случаях нужный фрагмент копируется в буфер обмена.
OS Fedora.

Comment: Но годится ли такое решение в обычный vim?

Comment: Да сейчас протестировал на vim, всё так же работает.