# Copy / Paste в Vim

Tags: vim, copy

Пару месяцев назад начал использовать Vim. Я освоился, мне всё нравится, но одно мне очень не нравится, когда я например, скопировал текст в браузере, и потом хочу его вставить в тест в Vim, мне постоянно приходится использовать мышь для этого. Также и с копированием из Vim, куда нибудь. Вопрос, есть ли возможность вместо мыши использовать клавиатуру, для того что я выше описал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers: `"+p` - вставить из буфера, `"+y` - копировать туда

Comment: [дубликаты косяком пошли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1004720/178576)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/970354/178576

Answer (score 2):

Я использую такую настройку:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Также в связке с этим будет полезно установить и эту:

```
set hidden
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте мапы и всё. Обычно в вим для копирования в общий буфер операционной системы используется сочетание "+y (на выделенном тексте) то

`vmap <C-c> "+y`  - сделает копирование по Ctrl с

`imap <C-v> <Esc>"+gp`   - вставит текст из буфера ОС в редактор по Ctrl v (в режиме вставки)

мапы вставляются в (.vimrc) конфиг файл для vim который, лежит в домашней директории в линукс.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я пользуюсь [плагином](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-system-copy) (нужен `xsel`):

```
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-system-copy'
```

`cp` - для копирования выделенной строки в системный буфер.

`cv` - для вставки из системного буфера обмена.

Comment: у вас тоже не работают [клавиатурные сочетания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004720/vim-ssh-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment1702133_1004720)?

Comment: Вставка работает, но временами криво. Код на `Python` начинает обрабатываться, например (знаю, что это отключается). Копирование - не работает. А вы можете выделить в `Vim` текст с помощью `v`, а потом отправить в буфер обмена Иксов через `Ctrl+Instert`, или аналоги?

Comment: упомянутые в моём комментарии сочетания клавиш к программе vim не имеют вообще никакого отношения. обработку их совершает эмулятор терминала, просто передавая текст из соответствующего буфера обмена выполняющейся внутри него программе (примерно так же, как если бы его вводили «руками»).

Comment: Откуда терминал может знать, что я в `vim` выделил? Поэтому эти сочетания для копирования из `Vim` не работают. Автор спросил: `Также и с копированием из Vim, куда нибудь.`

Comment: я всего лишь спросил: «у вас тоже не работают клавиатурные сочетания?»